# Label next to a label with variable length

Tags: ios

I would like to have tableview's row which contains two labels. First will contains a name which can be different length and the second one will contain a number in brackets. For example :

|Example Name (8)                         |
|Example very very long name (10)|
|Exmaple very very very very... (21)|
|Name (6)                                        |
|Example name name name n...(2)|

Rows with dots should be scrollable. Second label should be always next to first one but if first is too long second label should still be visible on the screen and first should be horizontally scrollable.

**Using DonMag's solution:**

It almost work. I get views that I wanted but left label is not scrollable. It has dots at the end and I can't see the rest part of label.

**My tableview:**

[image]

**Constraints:**

[image]

**Right label:**

[image]

**Scroll View:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting content hugging priority for both the labels ? High value of hugging priority will take the priority and expand the intrinsic size.

Comment: I have added Label1's settings to my question. This settings doesn't work.

Comment: @matekome - not quite clear what you're trying to do. If your labels are (`L1`) "abc" and (`L2`) "123456789", you want it displayed with `L1` followed by a small space then `L2` followed by a large space to the edge of the view? And as `L1` has more text, it *pushes* `L2` to the right, until `L2` hits the edge and then `L1` scrolls? Or do you want it to start as in your image, with `L2` *always* at the right edge?

Comment: I have extended my example. Please look at my edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little tricky, but not too tricky...

What you need to do is set multiple, similar constraints and use a combination of `Content Compression Resistance Priority` ***and*** `Constraint Priority` on the different elements.

Take a look at this:

[image]

- We embed Left Label in a scroll view.
- We constrain the width of the scroll view to the width of the label, but with a Priority of `750`. That will allow the scroll view to expand (and contract) with the label **until** it can't expand anymore.
- We add constraints to Right Label... leading to the scroll view, and trailing to the right edge of the view, with the trailing set to `>= 20` and the compression resistance set to `1000`. That allows the label to "stick" to the scroll view as it expands / contracts, but will ***not*** allow it to go past the right edge, nor compress past its own content width.
- The rest of the constraints are pretty standard.

And we get:

[image]

I whipped up a simple example that will let you change the text with button taps to see it in action:

[image]

Here's the class:

```
class ScrollingLabelViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func leftTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton {

            let t = btn.currentTitle

            switch t {

            case "Short Text":
                leftLabel.text = "Example Name"

            case "Medium Text":
                leftLabel.text = "Example Longer Name"

            case "Long Text":
                fallthrough

            default:
                leftLabel.text = "Example Name that is long enough that it will need to scroll."

            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func rightTap(_ sender: Any) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton {

            let t = btn.currentTitle

            switch t {

            case "Short Text":
                rightLabel.text = "(6)"

            case "Medium Text":
                rightLabel.text = "(255)"

            case "Long Text":
                fallthrough

            default:
                rightLabel.text = "(38,872)"

            }
        }
    }

}
```

And the Storyboard source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="itP-Si-dAD">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Scrolling Label View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="2HK-o9-I65">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="itP-Si-dAD" customClass="ScrollingLabelViewController" customModule="XC10SWScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="C9r-ad-Wv2">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Rs3-TC-hFe">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="60" width="114.5" height="20.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Example Name" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3jj-Oq-9XF">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="114.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.99143940210000003" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" secondAttribute="bottom" id="7EF-mm-DaK"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" secondAttribute="width" priority="750" id="ZtX-rP-Lme"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" constant="12" id="ZyU-il-ReF"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" secondAttribute="top" id="ml2-6X-bBl"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" secondAttribute="leading" id="r4q-LE-OQ5"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" secondAttribute="trailing" id="t9q-89-BOF"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" secondItem="3jj-Oq-9XF" secondAttribute="height" id="xDp-np-bFT"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="(6)" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZCj-c5-IzQ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="142.5" y="60" width="23" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.99143940210000003" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="47" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0v3-eY-MTM">
                                <rect key="frame" x="44" y="160.5" width="287" height="164.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="18" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nou-P9-haw">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="120" height="164.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Left Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Jgc-gS-1Oz">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="120" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mPG-zF-zdi">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="38.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Short Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="leftTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="z5m-yd-ACM"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xiv-Uc-UPL">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="86.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Medium Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="leftTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="hCp-75-WVo"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="LQD-gc-Pv1">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="134.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Long Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="leftTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="fWI-cl-wGZ"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="120" id="Mvo-co-QSU"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="18" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="usT-YQ-P4a">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="167" y="0.0" width="120" height="164.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Right Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WXA-Lo-BaW">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="120" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UXZ-r3-dw1">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="38.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Short Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="rightTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="1e8-Dh-iHD"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BN2-Tt-2QG">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="86.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Medium Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="rightTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="8CM-Gx-TYM"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="vCy-ut-LXL">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="134.5" width="120" height="30"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Long Text"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <action selector="rightTap:" destination="itP-Si-dAD" eventType="touchUpInside" id="iTb-4n-jbd"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="120" id="ACw-Tb-RfF"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="N2s-Cz-Yp4" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="Dkw-df-pKY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZCj-c5-IzQ" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" secondAttribute="centerY" id="GsG-U4-jc6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZCj-c5-IzQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="aVZ-i7-91I"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="N2s-Cz-Yp4" secondAttribute="top" constant="40" id="jFX-1U-cRh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="0v3-eY-MTM" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="C9r-ad-Wv2" secondAttribute="centerX" id="jZO-qZ-0z5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="N2s-Cz-Yp4" firstAttribute="trailing" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="ZCj-c5-IzQ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="pP1-gC-Uvq"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="0v3-eY-MTM" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Rs3-TC-hFe" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="80" id="sJi-4A-BOA"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="N2s-Cz-Yp4"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="leftLabel" destination="3jj-Oq-9XF" id="469-ke-ni2"/>
                        <outlet property="rightLabel" destination="ZCj-c5-IzQ" id="hMG-sN-B29"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="w9F-EF-F89" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="167" y="1506"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

---

**Edit:** pretty much the same thing, but setup as a XIB for use as a table view cell.

[image]

`ScrollingLabelCell.xib` in IB:

[image]

`ScrollingLabelCell.xib` source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="SVi-M2-eJO" customClass="ScrollingLabelCell" customModule="XC10SWScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="SVi-M2-eJO" id="FO6-8m-8lR">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1TD-My-nqW" userLabel="Inner View">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fPZ-Vc-pTX">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="11.5" width="114.5" height="20.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Example Name" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Gsx-qe-uXG">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="114.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KNJ-P5-R1c"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" secondAttribute="top" id="M63-Na-FHd"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" secondItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" secondAttribute="height" id="kQb-o9-Cmr"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" secondAttribute="leading" id="od5-IF-Drl"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" secondAttribute="trailing" id="pVh-95-8bc"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Gsx-qe-uXG" secondAttribute="width" priority="750" id="zUu-pN-rme"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="(6)" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cnK-Pa-DDF">
                                <rect key="frame" x="142.5" y="11.5" width="23" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1TD-My-nqW" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="24S-Dy-Pf7"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="cnK-Pa-DDF" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="9P7-Or-S8M"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="11.5" id="BD3-7Z-Ry9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="cnK-Pa-DDF" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Q4G-6M-3Qe"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1TD-My-nqW" secondAttribute="top" constant="11.5" id="lOh-MF-Khj"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="cnK-Pa-DDF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fPZ-Vc-pTX" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="mVz-me-wRN"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="1TD-My-nqW" secondAttribute="bottom" id="fgL-GE-OC3"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="1TD-My-nqW" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="FO6-8m-8lR" secondAttribute="leading" id="iV5-qZ-Oq7"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="1TD-My-nqW" secondAttribute="trailing" id="whk-Ke-oc7"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="1TD-My-nqW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="FO6-8m-8lR" secondAttribute="top" id="yIU-Lz-jlC"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="leftLabel" destination="Gsx-qe-uXG" id="9kR-67-2oC"/>
                <outlet property="rightLabel" destination="cnK-Pa-DDF" id="p4k-MJ-gb2"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="156" y="50.374812593703155"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

and example cell and table view controller classes:

```
class ScrollingLabelCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!

}

class ScrollingLabelTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let xibName = "ScrollingLabelCell"

    let theData: [[String]] = [
        ["Example Name", "1"],
        ["Example Longer Name", "2"],
        ["Example Even Longer Name", "3"],
        ["To demonstrate the scrolling,", "4"],
        ["6, 7 & 800 have the same name", "5"],
        ["Mr. Example Name that is Long Enough that it Needs to Scroll", "6"],
        ["Mr. Example Name that is Long Enough that it Needs to Scroll", "7"],
        ["Mr. Example Name that is Long Enough that it Needs to Scroll", "800"],
        ["Back to Short Names", "99"],
        ["With longer numbers", "2,750"],
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: xibName, bundle: bundle)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: xibName)

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: xibName, for: indexPath) as! ScrollingLabelCell

        cell.leftLabel.text = theData[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.rightLabel.text = "(" + theData[indexPath.row][1] + ")"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try using the code and Storyboard that I posted? Because that worked for me, including scrolling the left label (see the screen cap). If you're getting truncated instead of scrolling, I suspect you're missing a constraint / setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this either with constraints, or you can try playing around with stackViews, since this is generally their intended use:

```
UIStackview

| Label 1 | UIScrollView (Label 2) |
```

In this case, just add the width constraint to the `scrollView` to be >= than your intended size and increase the vertical priority for the `label 1`.

I would also reconsider against having the label inside a scrollView, inside another scrollView (your tableView in this specific case) since it will be pretty janky to get something that small to scroll. Probably better to just consider placing the labels one underneath the other or some other layout improvement requiring less tweaking and having a better UX.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood me well. First label should be scrollable if is too long. So i will scroll something which is not too small to scroll. I only whant want twol labels next to each other in one row but second label should be always visible. I don't want second label be out of the screen so if first label is too long it should be scrollable but second one should be still on the screen.

Comment: The principle is still the same, wherever the scrollView is.